# Implementing ES6 Map augmented with metadata in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dictionary, generics

I need a Map where a key is associated not only with value but also with some metadata - like 'weight' or 'timeToLive'.

First, an example interface for Map holding items of different weights:

```ts
export interface Weighted {
    weight: number
}
```

...and a type alias to merge all the metadata interfaces with actual value to hold in a Map:

```ts
type AugmValue<V, M> = M & {
    value: V;
}
```

I took the built-in Map and extended it. As of generic types:

- M is for metadata interfaces, like `Weighted & Ttl`
- K is a type of keys
- V is a type of actual values

... and implementation:

```ts
export class MdaMap<M, K, V> extends Map<K, AugmValue<V, M>> {
    constructor(records: [K, V, M][] = []) {
        const result: [K, AugmValue<V, M>][] = [];
        for (const [key, val, meta] of records) {
            result.push([key, Object.assign({value: val}, meta)]);
        }
        super(result);
    }

    get(key: K): V | undefined {
        const t = super.get(key);
        return typeof t === 'undefined' ? undefined : t.value;
    }
}
```

However, `get` gets underlined with lenghty message ending with:

```
Type 'V' is not assignable to type 'AugmValue<V, M>'.
      Type 'V' is not assignable to type 'M'.
```

How to correctly implement it? It is simplified case, eventually I'd like to have `get()` method like so:

```ts
get(key: K, meta: keyof AugmValue<V, M> = 'value'): AugmValue<V, M> [keyof M | "value"] | undefined {
    const t = super.get(key);
    return typeof t === 'undefined' ? undefined : t[meta];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extend `Map<K, AugmValue<V, M>>`, your extension needs to implement [that interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.1.1/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L21-L29), meaning that `get(key: K)` needs to return `AugmValue<V, M>> | undefined`, not `V | undefined`.

One possibility available to you is to [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) the `get()` method so that it still implements the required signature but also accepts an additional argument to give the extra behavior:

```
export class MdaMap<M, K, V> extends Map<K, AugmValue<V, M>> {

  get(key: K): AugmValue<V, M> | undefined;
  get<AK extends keyof AugmValue<V, M>>(
    key: K, 
    augmentedValueKey: AK
  ): AugmValue<V, M>[AK] | undefined;
  get<AK extends keyof AugmValue<V, M>>(
    key: K, 
    augmentedValueKey?: AK
  ): AugmValue<V, M> | AugmValue<V, M>[AK] | undefined {
    const t = super.get(key);
    return typeof augmentedValueKey === 'undefined' ? t : 
      typeof t === 'undefined' ? undefined : t[augmentedValueKey];
  }

}

const mdaMap = new MdaMap([["a", true, { weight: 4 }], ["b", false, { weight: 17 }]]);
const augmented = mdaMap.get("a"); // AugmValue<boolean, Weighted> | undefined
const unaugmented = mdaMap.get("a", "value"); // boolean | undefined
const weight = mdaMap.get("a", "weight"); // number | undefined
```

This has the (possibly minor) drawback that `get(key)` doesn't return what you were hoping, and you need to call `get(key, "value")` instead... but it has the huge advantage of being terse and properly typed.

---

If you do really need to make some sort of derived class that is incompatible with the base class (if `get(key)` needs to return a `V | undefined`), then you can't use `extends`, since you are not producing a valid subtype.  In such situations usually the advice is that your new class instance should *have* an instance of the base class, instead of trying to *be* an instance of the base class.  This is called [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).  This is conceptually clear but in practice pretty annoying to implement, since it ends up mostly forwarding methods to the held instance:

```
class OtherMap<M, K, V> {
  private innerMap: Map<K, AugmValue<V, M>> = new Map();
  constructor(records: [K, V, M][] = []) {
    this.innerMap = new Map(records.map(
      ([k, v, m]) => [k, Object.assign({ value: v }, m)] as [K, AugmValue<V, M>]
    ));
  }
  clear(): void {
    return this.innerMap.clear();
  }
  delete(key: K): boolean {
    return this.innerMap.delete(key);
  }
  forEach(callbackfn: (value: M & { value: V; }, key: K, map: OtherMap<M, K, V>) => void, thisArg?: any): void {
    return this.innerMap.forEach((v, k) => callbackfn(v, k, this), thisArg);
  }
  get(key: K): V | undefined {
    return (this.innerMap.get(key) || { value: undefined }).value;
  }
  has(key: K): boolean {
    return this.innerMap.has(key);
  }
  set(key: K, value: M & { value: V; }): this {
    this.innerMap.set(key, value);
    return this;
  }
  get size(): number {
    return this.innerMap.size;
  }
  [Symbol
    .iterator](): IterableIterator<[K, M & { value: V; }]> {
    return this.innerMap[Symbol.iterator]();
  }
  entries(): IterableIterator<[K, M & { value: V; }]> {
    return this.innerMap.entries();
  }
  keys(): IterableIterator<K> {
    return this.innerMap.keys();
  }
  values(): IterableIterator<M & { value: V; }> {
    return this.innerMap.values();
  }
  [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Map";
}
```

That's such a pain that I wonder if you should just *use* a `Map<K, AugmValue<V, M>>` instead of trying to create a new class at all?

---

Anyway, hope one of those ideas gives you some help.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for exhaustive answer. I contemplated 2 ways of doing it. First was extending the Map - and as you pictured it this solution turns out to be undesirable and confusing. So second option was creating wrapper around Map - but as you noted it's tedious and... unpleasant. Still, I'd like to have clean and painless interface so using `Map<K, AugmValue<V, M>>` doesn't satisfy me.

However, I wonder if re-implementing a Map wouldn't be a way to go. I intend to ask about implementation details on SO, so I'll see.

Thanks again for answering, that was illuminating