# Re-implementing a Map in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, dictionary

As I need a Map where a key is associated not only with value but also with some metadata - like 'weight' or 'timeToLive', I was trying to use Map-based structure in form like `class MdaMap<M, K, V> extends Map<K, AugmValue<V, M>>`. As answered in [Implementing ES6 Map augmented with metadata in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578541/implementing-es6-map-augmented-with-metadata-in-typescript) it isn't good approach. Second option would be a wrapper object around a Map but feels like meh. So I thought about third option: reimplementing Map.

So I make a class that has to hold records of 3 kinds: keys, values and metadata.

```
class MdaMap<K, V, M> {
```

K is for keys, V for values and M for metadata. Now, question: what data structure would be best. I see following solutions:

1. array of tuples:

   ```
   private store: [K, V, M][];
   ```
2. array of objects:

   ```
   private store: {key: K, value: V, metadata: M}[]
   ```
3. 3 arrays:

   ```
   private keys: K[];
   private values: V[];
   private metadata: M[];
   ```

Solutions 1. and 2. require looping through the array until given key is found. The difference seems to be the convenience in accessing key, value or metadata - otherwise I suspect tuple is easier on the resources.

As for 3. I'd have to remember to set and delete the element in all three arrays of course and that's no problem. But I wonder if it's possible that if the MdaMap would be in a shared object the `keys`, `values` and `metadata` array could desynchronize if say, at the same time there is a call to the `set(k: K, v: V, m: M): void` and to `del(k: K): void`?

What in your opinion is the best approach and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to re-implement `Map`; just use it with a tuple as the contents:

```
private store: Map<K, [V, M]>;
```

Now you can still index into the map with your key, and then you peel off either the value or metadata from what you get back.

```
private store = new Map<string, [number, string]>();
store.set('duck', [1.50, 'yellow']);
store.set('firetruck', [8.49, 'red']);
```